# "Generics" in Objective-C to do a RangeValidator?

Tags: objective-c

In C# I could do this:

```
class RangeValidator<T> {
    public T MinValue { get; set; }
    public T MaxValue { get; set; }
}
```

Where T could be any primitive type; `int`, `float`, `double`... or any "object"-type; `String`, `DateTime` etc.

If in Obj-C, I did it like this:

```
@interface RangeValidator {
    id minValue;
    id maxValue;
}
@property ...
```

It would work for let's say a NSNumber or NSString, but if I assigned a NSInteger to minValue I'd get something like a

```
warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
// Since an id is a pointer to an object, not an integer. Correct?
```

The obvious solution here is maybe to use a NSNumber instead. I was just curious if there are any other solutions to this kind of problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way would be to use a `NSNumber` and initialize from the integer with

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:someInt];
```

This way the class does not need generics, you could easily perform validation by checking if `minValue` and `maxValue` e.g. understands `intValue` (or some comparison selector maybe, depending on what you want to do).

```
if([minValue respondsToSelector:@selector(intValue)]) {
    return [minValue intValue];
} else {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use generics in Objective C, I recommend you using Objective C++ which supports C++ template instead of this ugly untyped code.

The code above doesn't work because NSInteger is a typedef for appropriate primitive type and not a pointer type. You should use a NSNumber wrapper instead.

Comment: Let's say I go for the NSNumber wrapper suggested... Does more objective-c people think the untyped code above (`id minValue; id maxValue;`) is **ugly**? So ugly that I must get into Objective-C++ ?

Comment: It depends on what you think is ugly. I think untyped languages are the wrong thing but others don't think so :-)

Comment: Got you. My problem is that I'm too lazy to get into ++ right now :) But thanks for the suggestion! It sounds like something worth taking a look at in the future.

Comment: Actually you can use very little of C++ templates to implement this things. As a consequence, you can use much more efficient and typesafe collections from stl. There are plenty of templates tutorials in the internet.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the idiomatic Objective-C solution would be exactly what you propose, use the `id` type and wrap primitive number values in an `NSNumber`. `NSInteger`, as Konstantin mentions, is a primitive type – see the [Foundation Data Type Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html):

```
#if __LP64__ || TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
#endif
```

This inconsistency between primitive types and objects is a bit unfortunate, you have to learn to recognize the non-object types like `NSInteger`, `CGRect` or `CMTime`.

Comment: Thanks zoul! I took your+Krumelur's advice to go for the wrapping in an NSNumber. In this case, do you share Konstantins opinion that the untyped code (`id minValue; id maxValue;`) is ugly? I thought that was how obj-c ppl liked it :)

Comment: I like to keep the type as precise as possible, but little loose typing here and there is not that bad. Certainly I would prefer the `id` solution to Objective-C++.